# uninitialized constant Scrubyt::Navigation::Mechanize::WWW (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize, scrubyt

I am using the Scrubyt gem, and when I use it, I get this error:

```
/home/bitnami/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/scrubyt-0.4.06/lib/scrubyt/core/navigation/agents/mechanize.rb:17:in `included': uninitialized constant Scrubyt::Navigation::Mechanize::WWW (NameError)
```

I have the following gems installed

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

builder (3.0.0)
commonwatir (2.0.1)
firewatir (1.9.3)
hoe (2.12.2)
hpricot (0.8.4)
mechanize (2.0.1)
net-http-digest_auth (1.1.1)
net-http-persistent (1.9)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
rake (0.9.2)
s4t-utils (1.0.4)
scrubyt (0.4.06)
user-choices (1.1.6.1)
webrobots (0.0.11)
xml-simple (1.1.0)
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I resolved this issue installing the exact versions of `hpricot` and `Mechanize`

```
sudo gem install hpricot -v 0.5
sudo gem install mechanize -v 0.6.3
```

then

```
sudo gem install scrubyt
```

but first I uninstalled previous gem versions with

```
sudo gem uninstall hpricot
sudo gem uninstall mechanize
```